# Cannot Find Symbol, Instance Field

Tags: java

I am student having a large amount of difficulty, constructing a game of Nim. When I build this file I get 2 errors saying cannot find symbol on lines 42 and 43

```
        Random rand = new Random();
            ...
        turn = nextInt(2);
```

Comment: Note, the `if (turn = 0)` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Also, note that it's important to provide the exact error message, not just part of it--like *which* symbol isn't found. Easiest to just cut-and-paste it; saves time for everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
rand.nextInt(12);
```